# HTML.ActionLink to details page not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, html.actionlink

Hi I'm having trouble working this one out. I want my header to be a link that redirects to the details

```
<div class="card-columns">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="card" style="width:300px">
            <img class="card-img-top" src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CoverArt) alt="Card image">
            <div class="card-body">
                @Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.Name, "Details", "Albums", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, null)
                <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Info)</p>
                <p class="card-text small">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

I found this on the internet but it throws an error:

> 'There is no argument given that corresponds to the required forma
>   parameter 'fragment' of 'IHtmlHelper.ActionLink(string, string,.....)'

Comment: The first parmeter of all ActionLink methods require a string.  So 

 @Html.ActionLink(modelItem => item.Name

should be
 @Html.ActionLink(item.Name

In addition, you should not be using any of the "for" helpers, e.g. DisplayFor, because you're not binding anything to the model, you're just iterating through the Model and displaying the values of each item.

Comment: I did that, the link worked but it opened the details page without the data of the item

Comment: You have your ID commented out in the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it worked:

```
<a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">
  <h4 class="card-title">
    @item.Name
  </h4>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `modelItem => item.Name` with `item.Name`

```
<div class="card-columns">
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="card" style="width:300px">
            <img class="card-img-top" src=@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CoverArt) alt="Card image">
            <div class="card-body">
                @Html.ActionLink(item.Name, "Details", "Albums", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, null)
                <p class="card-text">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Info)</p>
                <p class="card-text small">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: I did that, the link worked but it opened the details page without the data of the item

Comment: Well, you are not far off then. Your 'routeValues' parameter which in your snippet appears commented out, should work if you have an ```AlbumsController``` with a ```Details(int id)``` action.